# Asymptote GL Compile error

Tags: asymptote

I've used Asymptote in the past to generate a large number of images. I've recently upgraded to version 2.65 and am having trouble getting simple files to compile. (To try to avoid confusion on my Windows 10 machine, I uninstalled all past versions of TeXLive and Asymptote, then reinstalled fresh copies. Also installed Ghostscript v 9.52.)

Here's my simple file, called `test.asy`:

```
size(5cm,0); 
import three; 
draw(unitcube);
```

If I compile with `asy -f html test.asy`, I see the unit cube in my browser just fine.

If I compile with `asy -f pdf test.asy`, I get a pdf that initially shows nothing, but in Adobe Reader I can click and get a rotateable 3D image.

If I compile with `asy -f pdf -noprc -render 0 test.asy`, I get a static pdf image of low quality. Same if I choose `... -f png ...`

But, if I compile with any other render setting (other than 0), or with no render statement at all, I get a very long error message.

What is going wrong? I'd like to construct a good quality 2D graphic (better than provided by `-render=0`).
Here's the error message:

```
Error: Preprocessor error
Error: failed to preprocess the source.

GL Compile error
#version 130
#extension GL_ARB_uniform_buffer_object : enable
#define WIDTH
#define Nlights 1
const int Nmaterials=48;
in vec3 position;

uniform mat3 normMat;

#ifdef NORMAL
#ifndef ORTHOGRAPHIC
out vec3 ViewPosition;
#endif
in vec3 normal;
out vec3 Normal;
#endif

in int material;

#ifdef COLOR
in vec4 color;
out vec4 Color;
#endif

#ifdef WIDTH
in float width;
#endif

uniform mat4 projViewMat;
uniform mat4 viewMat;

flat out int materialIndex;

void main()
{
  vec4 v=vec4(position,1.0);
  gl_Position=projViewMat*v;
#ifdef NORMAL
#ifndef ORTHOGRAPHIC
  ViewPosition=(viewMat*v).xyz;
#endif
  Normal=normalize(normal*normMat);
#endif

#ifdef COLOR
  Color=color;
#endif

#ifdef WIDTH
  gl_PointSize=width;
#endif

  materialIndex=material;
}

terminate called after throwing an instance of 'int'
```

Comment: Send a mail to John or send a mail to the asymptote help...

Comment: I posted this same request on the Sourceforge/Asymptote page yesterday. While I'm not in a rush, I didn't hear back so I thought I'd post here, too.

Comment: I ran into an issue with the render that John said was a result of not having OpenGL on my mac: https://github.com/vectorgraphics/asymptote/issues/96. I've not investigated since.